# For what Value of K, the following system of equations will have No Solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

2x-8y = 3

Kx+4y = 10

i can use trial and hit method but its inconvenient and time-consuming, if there is any alternative methods to obtain a solution for these sort of problems, please Let me know.
Thanx for this little help! :)

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CramersRule.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By multiplying the second equation with $2$, the given system can be written as $$\begin{cases} 2x&-&8y&=&3 \\ 2Kx&+&8y&=&20 \end{cases}$$ Adding the two equations gives $$2(K+1)x=23$$ which cannot hold when $K=-1$. For values of $K\neq-1$ you have that $$x=\frac{23}{2(K+1)}$$ and $$y=\frac18\left(\frac{23}{(K+1)}-3\right)$$

Comment: it was very clear to understand, helped me a lot.

Comment: @RoshanJha you are welcome mate!

Answer (score 2):

Second equation can be re-written as: $-2Kx-8y=-20$
When the left hand side of the above equation is equal to the left hand side of the first equation, i.e. $2x-8y=3$, we can say that the system has no solutions as the same left hand side cannot have two different values.

So:$$-2K=2 \implies K=-1$$

If you are new to this you can refer to Consistent and Inconsistent solutions for system of equations.

Comment: it helped.. thanx.